Puppeteer "Could not find Chromium" error on Vercel deployment
I'm deploying a Node.js application to Vercel that uses the capture-website npm package (which uses Puppeteer under the hood) to generate website screenshots. Locally, everything works fine, but on Vercel, I'm getting the following error:
Error making capture-website call: Could not find Chromium (rev. ...). This can occur if either
 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/sbx_user1051/.cache/puppeteer).
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.

My package.json includes:
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "capture-website": "^3.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.15",
    "openai": "^4.38.2",
    "validator": "^13.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  } 

How can I resolve this "Could not find Chromium" error on Vercel?

Puppeteer isn't in your dependencies.

Hello, I know, it's used as a sub-dependency of the capture-website module, and it's listed inside my package-lock.json file properly. I just noticed that the Vercel environment is not using Chromium and I can't seem to load it at all. I've faced the exact same issue on Heroku in the past. I've never been able to make these environments load Chromium for some reason, and I can't find a solution for months now.

Chromium also needs a lot of os packages installed so you need a specialized container

You mean starting with a Vercel template for Chromium/Puppeteer?

No I'm saying I don't think you can do it in Vercel functions, you can do it in Lambda because they let you install os packages
